# Skipping a query field on IF condition

Tags: mysql

My MySQL query is sent to a csv, and then to a HTML file.
When I do...

```
SELECT
field_a,
IF($VAR="yes",field_b,""),
field_c
FROM table
INTO OUTFILE "query.csv";
```

...I always get 3 columns (field_a, field_b or empty, field_c), as expected.
How can I get only 2 columns (field_a, field_c) when $VAR is not "yes"?

Comment: You can't. The query result cannot have variable number of columns. Nevertheless you can concatenate the values of your three fields to a single value

Comment: Can't you test `$VAR` first then just split it into two different select statements?

Comment: Yes, I can a)split the select statements, b)use two different scripts, and c)use sed to remove the third column from the csv once it is created, which I think will be the best solution to keep my code simple and clean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Build your query dynamically. It looks like your `$VAR` condition does not depend on the data. Then you may do this (example in PHP):

```
$fields = 'field_a' ;
if ($VAR == 'yes') $fields .= ', field_b' ; // and so on
$query = "SELECT $fields FROM table" ;
```

Comment: Couldn't use it because I don't use PHP. My way was `cut -d ";" -f 1-2,4-99 < csv0.txt > csv.txt` Thanks anyhow!